# Initializing a vector with a vector of vector causes segmentation fault in C++

Tags: c++

I was revisiting and old project of backtracking that aimed to solve a problem similar to Rat in the Maze and found this chunk of code that for some reason causes a segmentation fault.

The isolated line in particular is the one causing the problem.

```
int makeDecision(vector<int> currPos, vector<vector<int> > board, vector<vector<int> > &visited){

    int M = board.size();
    int N = board[0].size();
    int currX = currPos[0];
    int currY = currPos[1];

    vector<int> prevPos = visited[visited.size()-2];

    int prevX = prevPos[0];
    int prevY = prevPos[1];
```

I believe it has something to do with being a double vector, but I'm not entirely sure.

---

This part is the principal function, that calls makeDecision()
decisions is a vector that stores the past choices, cPos stands for current position and visited is another vector for checking the places the code has been

```
void backtracking(vector<vector<int> > board, vector<int> &decisions, vector<int> & cPos, vector<vector<int> > &visited)
{
    int M = board.size();
    int N = board[0].size();
    vector<int> currPos;
    if (cPos[0] == N - 1 && cPos[1] == M - 1)
        cout << "\nYou found the exit :D" << endl; // Base case
    else
    {
        int d = makeDecision(cPos, board, visited);
        decisions.push_back(d);
        backtracking(board, decisions, cPos, visited);
    }
}
```

---

And lastly, this is my main function

```
    int m;
    cout << "Enter M: ";
    cin >> m;

    int n;
    cout << "Enter N: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "\nCreaate board" << endl;
    vector<vector<int> > b = createBoard(m,n);

    cout << "\nPrinting...";
    printBoard(b);

    cout << "Solving..." << endl;

    vector<vector<int> > visited;
    vector<int> decisions = {0,0};
    vector<int> cPos;
    cPos.push_back(0);
    cPos.push_back(0);


    backtracking(b, decisions, cPos, visited);

    return 0;
```

---

If needed, I'm compiling with g++ and C++11

A full version of my code is available [here](https://pastebin.com/SDnVbAcB)

Comment: Can `visited.size()` be <= 1 ?

Comment: Please show a [MCVE] and explain what exactly the code should do. Also, you can (and should) debug your code to get more information than "for some reason causes a segmentation fault".

Comment: Because of the indices you are using into the vectors, the code has undefined behavior if any of `visited`, `currPos` and `visited[size()-2]` don't have at least size `2` or if `board` is empty. Otherwise the execution of the shown lines of code is well-defined. There isn't really more to say about what you have shown. Your program logic is probably flawed in some way, taking into account the preconditions on the shown code I mentioned.

Comment: Segmentation faults can frequently occur some time after their root cause. Unless visited.size() < 2 or other things aren't big enough, I don't believe the problem is coming from this code. Something earlier could have corrupted memory which is causing the symptom to appear here.

Comment: If you have the compiler options `-fsanitize=undefined,address` available to you, I'd suggest trying to see if that helps in tracking things down.

Comment: I've edited my post, as requested by @Dmitry. At first, I'd assume the problem is visited being empty, but I tried initializing it and I still get the same error.

Comment: @AlexM., thanks, but please check the link I shared again. Your example neither complete (e.g. `createBoard` is undefined, inputs are unknown (the code you post here shouldn't require any user input, when possible)) nor minimal. I suspect that in your case, the whole code can be minimized to 1-3 non-trivial lines. And if you don't know how to debug the code, it's time to learn! `gdb` is the keyword; if you use an IDE, it should have a neat interface for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is in this section, it is likely that one of the assumptions about sizes of inputs is not correct. You can put `assert` calls to check them before doing anything.

```
int makeDecision(vector<int> currPos, vector<vector<int> > board, vector<vector<int> > &visited){
    assert(board.size()>0);
    assert(currPos.size()>1);
    assert(visited.size()>1);
    assert(visited[visited.size()-2].size()>1);

    int M = board.size();
    int N = board[0].size();
    int currX = currPos[0];
    int currY = currPos[1];

    vector<int> prevPos = visited[visited.size()-2];

    int prevX = prevPos[0];
    int prevY = prevPos[1];
```